# How to connect with a file socket and not with the TCP protocol?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I can connect with the command:

```
bin/mysql -h localhost -P 3306 --protocol=tcp -u europasprak -p db_europasprak
```

But I cannot connect with the command:

```
bin/mysql -P 3306 -u europasprak -p db_europasprak
```

It fails as in:

```
europasprak@vps-3506b083:~/programs/mariadb/install$ bin/mysql -P 3306 -u europasprak -p db_europasprak
Enter password: 
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '~/programs/mariadb/install/tmp/mariadb.sock' (2)
```

The socket file exists:

```
europasprak@vps-3506b083:~/programs/mariadb/install$ ll ~/programs/mariadb/install/tmp/mariadb.sock
srwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 juil. 11 20:20 /home/europasprak/programs/mariadb/install/tmp/mariadb.sock
```

And my PHP application cannot connect with the statement:

```
mysqli_connect("localhost", "europasprak", "examplepassword", "db_europasprak", "3306")
```

When the MariaDB server starts its console shows:

```
210711 20:20:56 mysqld_safe Starting mariadbd daemon with databases from /home/europasprak/dev/docker/projects/common/volumes/database/mariadb/data
2021-07-11 20:20:56 0 [Note] /home/europasprak/programs/mariadb/install/bin/mariadbd (mysqld 10.5.9-MariaDB-log) starting as process 3477606 ...
2021-07-11 20:20:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2021-07-11 20:20:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2021-07-11 20:20:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2021-07-11 20:20:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using crc32 + pclmulqdq instructions
2021-07-11 20:20:56 0 [Note] mariadbd: O_TMPFILE is not supported on /tmp (disabling future attempts)
2021-07-11 20:20:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 134217728, chunk size = 134217728
2021-07-11 20:20:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2021-07-11 20:20:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting log file ./ib_logfile101 size to 100663296 bytes
2021-07-11 20:20:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: Renaming log file ./ib_logfile101 to ./ib_logfile0
2021-07-11 20:20:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: New log file created, LSN=957285982
2021-07-11 20:20:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segments are active.
2021-07-11 20:20:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2021-07-11 20:20:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2021-07-11 20:20:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2021-07-11 20:20:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.5.9 started; log sequence number 0; transaction id 9570669
2021-07-11 20:20:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /home/europasprak/dev/docker/projects/common/volumes/database/mariadb/data/ib_buffer_pool
2021-07-11 20:20:56 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2021-07-11 20:20:56 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
2021-07-11 20:20:56 0 [Note] Reading of all Master_info entries succeeded
2021-07-11 20:20:56 0 [Note] Added new Master_info '' to hash table
2021-07-11 20:20:56 0 [Note] /home/europasprak/programs/mariadb/install/bin/mariadbd: ready for connections.
Version: '10.5.9-MariaDB-log'  socket: '/home/europasprak/programs/mariadb/install/tmp/mariadb.sock'  port: 3306  Source distribution
2021-07-11 20:20:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 210711 20:20:56
```

The `phpinfo()` shows the `myslqi` to be enabled and having the values:

```
Client API library version  mysqlnd 5.0.12-dev - 20150407 - $Id: 7cc7cc96e675f6d72e5cf0f267f48e167c2abb23 $
Active Persistent Links 0
Inactive Persistent Links   0
Active Links    0
Directive   Local Value Master Value
mysqli.allow_local_infile   Off Off
mysqli.allow_persistent On  On
mysqli.default_host no value    no value
mysqli.default_port 3306    3306
mysqli.default_pw   no value    no value
mysqli.default_socket   /home/europasprak/programs/mariadb/install/tmp/mysql.sock   /home/europasprak/programs/mariadb/install/tmp/mysql.sock
mysqli.default_user no value    no value
mysqli.max_links    Unlimited   Unlimited
mysqli.max_persistent   Unlimited   Unlimited
mysqli.reconnect    Off Off
mysqli.rollback_on_cached_plink Off Off
```

The `etc/my.cnf` file contains:

```
[mysqld]
bind-address    = 0.0.0.0 # Allow client binding from any IP address instead of just 127.0.0.1
port            = 3306
sql_mode        = NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION # This is strict mode: NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES
socket          = /home/europasprak/programs/mariadb/install/tmp/mariadb.sock
user            = root
basedir         = /home/europasprak/programs/mariadb/install
datadir         = /home/europasprak/dev/docker/projects/common/volumes/database/mariadb/data
log-error       = /home/europasprak/dev/docker/projects/common/volumes/logs/mariadb.error.log
general_log     = 1
general-log-file     = /home/europasprak/dev/docker/projects/common/volumes/logs/mariadb.log
slow-query-log-file  = /home/europasprak/dev/docker/projects/common/volumes/logs/mariadb.slow.queries.log
innodb_file_per_table = 1
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1
innodb_flush_method = O_DIRECT
character-set-client-handshake = FALSE
character-set-server = utf8mb4
collation-server = utf8mb4_general_ci
wait_timeout            = 28800 # amount of seconds during inactivity that MySQL will wait before it will close a connection on a non-interactive connection
interactive_timeout     = 28800 # same, but for interactive sessions
max_allowed_packet = 256M
net_write_timeout = 180

# Creating a binary log for change data capture
server-id = 1
log_bin = master
expire_logs_days = 1
binlog_format = row
binlog_row_image = full

[client]
socket          = /home/europasprak/programs/mariadb/install/tmp/mariadb.sock
loose-default-character-set = utf8mb4

[mysql]
loose-default-character-set = utf8mb4

[mysqladmin]
socket          = /home/europasprak/programs/mariadb/install/tmp/mariadb.sock
```

The MariaDB server is started with the command:

```
cd /home/europasprak/programs/mariadb/install
./bin/mysqld_safe --defaults-file=/home/europasprak/programs/mariadb/install/etc/my.cnf
```

UPDATE and solution:

I was missing a loaded `my.cnf` file:

```
europasprak@vps-3506b083:~/programs/mariadb/install$ bin/mysqld --verbose --help | grep -A 1 "Default options"
bin/mysqld: One can only use the --user switch if running as root
Default options are read from the following files in the given order:
/etc/my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf ~/.my.cnf 
europasprak@vps-3506b083:~/programs/mariadb/install$ ll /etc/mysql/my.cnf
ls: cannot access '/etc/mysql/my.cnf': No such file or directory
europasprak@vps-3506b083:~/programs/mariadb/install$ ll /etc/my.cnf
ls: cannot access '/etc/my.cnf': No such file or directory
```

Creating a simlink on the file solved the issue:

```
 ln -s /home/europasprak/programs/mariadb/install/etc/my.cnf ~/.my.cnf
```

Comment: Can you specify the socket on the command line, like: `bin/mysql --socket=/home/europasprak/programs/mariadb/install/tmp/mariadb.sock -u europasprak -p ...`? I'm wondering if you have the socket path with `~` in your `.my.cnf` maybe it can't do the tilde-substitution. You may be able to change it to use the full path.

Comment: Wait ! Your question leads me to some other question. I don't think I use the ~ tilde anywhere here. So how come the error log shows such a ~ tilde ?

Comment: Check your options files. Like your `~/.my.cnf` file, and also the system my.cnf which may be in `/etc` or wherever. I don't know where MariaDB assumes its option file is on your system (is it MacOS?). See https://mariadb.com/kb/en/configuring-mariadb-with-option-files/

Comment: But I have only one `my.cnf` file and it is displayed above.

Comment: Did you try the command I suggested, where you specify the `--socket` option on the command line? This will override any value in an option file.

Comment: @Stephane There are several log files configured. Can you add the log file entries related to your login attempt to your question? Also add the result of `strace bin/mysql -P ...` to your question as well. Is the directory `/home/europasprak/programs/mariadb/install/tmp/` readable for everyone?

Comment: Using the command `bin/mysql --socket=/home/europasprak/programs/mariadb/install/tmp/mariadb.sock -P 3306 -u europasprak -p db_europasprak` did successfully connect. There is no `~/.my.cnf` file. There is only one `/home/europasprak/programs/mariadb/install/etc/my.cnf` file.

Comment: I solved the issue by adding a soft link file `ln -s /home/europasprak/programs/mariadb/install/etc/my.cnf ~/.my.cnf` Now the client which can use the `~/.my.cnf` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leave out the port number from your connect strings. You don't use ports when you connect via sockets; that's a TCP thing.

Try this:
`bin/mysql -u europasprak -p db_europasprak`
or
`mysqli_connect("localhost", "europasprak", "examplepassword", "db_europasprak"`)

Comment: I'll accept your answer even if it was not really the solution to my issue, which I had already solved as seen in my question update section. But yours makes a valuable point anyway. And it's right I can give the point, if not credit, to someone.